# Best sources on data stream algorithms

Tags: reference-request, big-list, data-streams

I recently got interested in data stream algorithms to the point that I'd like to study the topic and then teach it to someone.

I'd be thus grateful for pointers to really good sources on the topic, t.i. papers presenting major ideas in a particularly articulate way, papers with clever proofs of clever theorems, just good overviews of the state of the art, whatever.

My two cents:

- [Lecture notes](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~ac/Teach/CS85-Fall09/Notes/lecnotes.pdf) from the Dartmouth University, 2009. This is the best source I've found so far.
- [Distributing Frequency-Dependent Data Stream Computations](http://crpit.com/confpapers/CRPITV94Ganguly.pdf), described in [my answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1290/divide-and-conquer-data-stream-algorithms/1340#1340) to a different (also mine) question.
- The book ["Data streams: algorithms and applications"](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~muthu/) (I haven't read it yet)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Piotr Indyk has some lecture notes on streaming and related topics at stellar.mit.edu/S/course/6/fa07/6.895

[A MADALGO summer school a few years ago](http://www.madalgo.au.dk/html_sider/2_5_Events/SS2007/FrontPage_SS2007.html) also has some good notes. I would say all the papers listed in the bibliography there are good reads for anyone interested in the area.

Answer (score 2):

Another source to track is [Andrew McGregor's blog](http://polylogblog.wordpress.com/).

Answer (score 2):

[Lecture](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~denis/notes09.pdf) from the 2009 Barbados Workshop on Computational Complexity touches some more recent topics.